# ScheduledExecutorService: modify one or more running tasks

Tags: threadpool, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a program, it loads a few tasks from a file prepared by user and start executing them according the scheduling shown in the file.

Example: taskFile.txt

```
Task1: run every hour
Task2: run every 2 seconds
...
TaskN: run every monday at 10:00
```

This first part is Ok, i solved by using ScheduledExecutorService and i am very satisfied. The tasks are load and run as they should.

Now, let's image that the user, by GUI (at runtime), decides that Task2 should run every minute, and he wants to remove Task3.
I cannot find any way to **access one specific task in the pool**, in order to remove/modify it.

So I cannot update tasks at runtime. When user changes a task, I can only modify the taskFile.txt and restart the application, in order to reload all tasks according the newly updated taskFile.txt.

Do you know any way to access a single task in order to modify/delete it?

Or even, a way to remove one given task, so i can insert a new one in the pool, with the modifications wanted by the user.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not elegant, but works.

Let's suppose you need 10 threads, and sometimes you need to manage a specific thread.

Instead to have a pool with 10 thread, use 10 pools with one thread for each, keep them in your favourite data structure, and act on the pool_1 when you want to modify thread_1.
It's possible to remove the older Runnable from the pool and put a new one with the needed changes.

Otherways, anything put in the pool became anonymous and will be not directly manageable.

If somebody has a better solution...